# Cannot access serial port

Tags: release-loki

I have installed OpenCPN which is navigation software that needs a GPS connection. I used the installation for Ubuntu 17 and the program works however when I try to connect my USB GPS dongle the program requires access to a serial port (because NMEA0183 data sent by the dongle is in serial format) An attempt to make a serial connection brings up a message saying I do not have access to serial ports on this system and tells me to exit and run the following in Terminal " sudo usermod-a-G dialout (followed by my username)".  This is not a valid command.
How do I get permanent access to serial ports?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo adduser <your_user_name> dialout
```

You will need to log out and back in again for this to take effect.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I tried it and it told me that I was already a member of dialout! however after a restart it has allowed me to connect the GPS dongle.  Problem Solved.  Now the problem is to get the dongle to get a GPS fix, but that is a dongle issue, not a Linux one.